# Have an Entity Framework field reference one of several derived tables via a discriminator (Using TPT)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to find a way to create this relationship from Entity Framework 5's Code First.

In the example below, I have some **Stock** which can either belong to a **Warehouse** or a **Row**.

**Stock Table**

```
'Id', 'SerialNo', 'Discriminator', 'LocationId'
345, ABC123, Warehouse, 4  
123, ABC124, Row, 12
```

**Warehouse Table**

```
'Id', 'Name'  
4, WH-One  
8, WH-Two
```

**Row Table**

```
'Id', 'Name'
6, RowA  
12, RowB
```

The **Discriminator** column on the table **Stock** determines which of the related tables the **LocationId** is referring to. For example:
**Stock** with **Id** '345' has a reference to row with Id: 4 (WH-One) on the **Warehouse** table

Can this type of relationship be mapped with EF Code First? It's certainly no trouble to query against this structure in SQL Server.

```
SELECT Stock.SerialNo, COALESCE(Warehouse.Name, Row.Name) AS Name
FROM Stock
LEFT OUTER JOIN Warehouse ON Stock.Id = Warehouse.Id AND Stock.Discriminator = 'Warehouse'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Row ON Stock.Id = Row.Id AND Stock.Discriminator = 'Row'
```

Which should return:

```
SerialNo, Name
ABC123, WH-One
ABC124, RowB
```

Ideally, I'd like to have either an interface or abstract base class which **Warehouse** and **Row** and derive from. And a navigation property called **Location** that would refer to either table cast to the abstract/interface.

Alternatively, I'd like to know if anyone has a better suggestion to describe a relationship in EF Code First that allows one entity to reference one of several other similar entities.

Answer (score 0):

It's *Code First* so I would do this:

*First* - create the classes I want in *code*:

```
public abstract class Location
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Stock> StockItems { get; set; }
}

public class Warehouse : Location
{
    public int NumberOfLoadingDocks { get; set; }
}

public class Row : Location
{
    public int NumberOfShelves { get; set; }
}

public class Stock
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SerialNo { get; set; }
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
}
```

Then add them to the context:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Warehouse> Warehouses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Package-Manager console:

```
Add-Migration "Locations"
Update-Database -Script
```

That lets me see the tables Entity Framework would create:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [SerialNo] [nvarchar](max),
    [LocationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Stocks] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_LocationID] ON [dbo].[Stocks]([LocationID])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    [NumberOfShelves] [int],
    [NumberOfLoadingDocks] [int],
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Locations] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Stocks_dbo.Locations_LocationID] FOREIGN KEY ([LocationID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([ID])
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201309120832257_Locations'....
```

Not the same tables that you have. This is [Table-per-Hierarchy inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/24/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph.aspx). If you are not happy with that then you need to look at [Table Per Type inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)

**EDIT**
To get TPT inheritance you can add the Table attribute to the inherited classes like this:

```
   [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Warehouses")]
    public class Warehouse : Location
    {
        public int NumberOfLoadingDocks { get; set; }
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Table("Rows")]
    public class Row : Location
    {
        public int NumberOfShelves { get; set; }
    }
```

And now you get separate tables for each type:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Locations] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Locations] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rows] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfShelves] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Rows] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[Rows]([ID])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Warehouses] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NumberOfLoadingDocks] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Warehouses] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[Warehouses]([ID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Stocks] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Stocks_dbo.Locations_LocationID] FOREIGN KEY ([LocationID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([ID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Rows] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rows_dbo.Locations_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([ID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Warehouses] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Warehouses_dbo.Locations_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Locations] ([ID])
```

And if you are not happy with that you should look at [Table Per Concrete Type Inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx)...

Comment: Thanks Colin, I was after the Table-per-Type inheritance chain though. TPH gets progressively more messy the more tables you derive from Location. the majority of columns being null. I suspect this would be optimum performance wise, it's just not very normalized or elegant. I think I would rather have redundant foreign keys on my Stock table than redundant columns on the Location table.

Comment: If you want table per type then add attributes to the derived tables. I have added an example in an edit